# How to cible and update a row in a nested data table after invoking an action listener

Tags: java-8, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I'm trying to figure out how to update my nested datatable DataTable_03 after calling the controller.createEntity() method.

```
<p:dataTable id="DataTable_01"
             rowIndexVar="rowIndexDT01" ...>

<p:dataTable id="DataTable_02"
             rowIndexVar="rowIndexDT02" ...>

<p:dataTable id="DataTable_03"
             rowIndexVar="rowIndexDT03" ...>

<p:menuitem
                    id="mi_01"
                    actionListener="#{controller.createEntity()}"
                    onclick="PF('DlgWidget').hide();"
                    update="form_entity:DataTable_01:#{rowIndexDT01}:DataTable_02:{rowIndexDT02}:DataTable_03, form_02, form_03, for_Resume">
```

When loading the page i'm receiving this exception:

```
01:22:22,464 ERROR [ErrorServlet] ErrorServlet
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Trying to extract rowIndex from clientId 'form_entity:DataTable_01::DataTable_02::DataTable_03' For input string: ":DataTable_02"
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can do what you are trying to do.  The datatable Index is only available inside the datatable and you are trying to use it in a menu item outside the datatable.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, i see. Is there any other alternatives?